# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<InfoIndividual> to String

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to return an arraylist to string value in java and I have this in spring hibernate application

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return _individuals;
    }
```

the above code gives me type mismatch.

this is the declaration

```
List<InfoIndividual> _individuals = new ArrayList<InfoIndividual>();
```

what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print a `Collection` you can use this workaround:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(_individuals.toArray());
}
```

---

If this does not fit your needs you can iterate the list while overriding toString of `InfoIndividual`.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (InfoIndividual i : _individuals) {
        sb.append(i);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

And:

```
class InfoIndividual {
    // attributes

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         // print needed attributes
    }

}
```

Comment: @Blaze this is default `toString()` output, you must override it as shown in second approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question does not give any details about how the resulting String should be formatted, you could simply use the list's toString-Method, which will produce an output like ["first", "second", "third"].

Assuming your InfoIndividual overrides toString appropiatley, you can just do something like this:

```
public String toString(){
  return _individuals.toString();
}
```